Cómo invocar instancias de una clase en otra distinta con Java (POO)
estoy aprendiendo a programar con Java , estoy viendo la POO y en el primer ejemplo que me han puesto, hemos creado una clase "Persona" con distintos estados o parámetros , junto con un método público para mostrar dichos estados o datos.
El problema está que cuando intento utilizar dicho método desde otra clase distinta , no me reconoce la clase Persona , a pesar de estar puesta como public. Adjunto el código y el error que me sale por terminal.
Tengo las dos clases en la misma carpeta.
Al crear un nuevo archivo me sale por defecto "Package" y el nombre de la carpeta ,lo cual no me pasaba hasta ahora.
Mil gracias de antemano.
public class Persona {
/* Persona es la CLASE , cada persona creada será una INSTANCIA */
String nombre;
int edad;
String ciudadResidencia;
String profesion;
String dni;


/* Para crear instancias de una clase , se usa un CONSTRUCTOR */

public Persona(){

    nombre = "Pablo";
    edad = 15;
    ciudadResidencia = "Jerez";
    profesion = "Estudiante";
    dni = "23023023A";
}



public void mostrarDatos(){

    System.out.println("Nombre: "+nombre);
    System.out.println("Edad: "+edad);
    System.out.println("Ciudad de residencia: "+ciudadResidencia);
    System.out.println("Profesión: "+profesion);
    System.out.println("Dni: "+dni);


}

}
Y ahora el otro archivo , en el que me da el error.
public class Ejm1OO {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Persona p1 = new Persona();
    Persona p2 = new Persona();

    p1.mostrarDatos();
}

}

¿Conocés el concepto de package?

y el error?? te falto eso...

Hola Pablo, estás usando un IDE?, por favor, edita tu pregunta y adjunta el arbol de directorios y si no usas un IDE, mostra como estás compilando el programa, y como te indican, el mensaje de error que recibis (todo como texto).

La verdad es que aún no he dado nada acerca de packages, pensé que serían como carpetas pero veo que son más influyentes , leeré al respecto, gracias @padaleiana .

He estado haciendo pruebas y al sacar ambos archivos de la carpeta en la que estaban , si se reconocen las clases públicas y puedo ejecutarlo , pero al volver a meterlos en la carpeta ya no me deja. El error que sale por terminal es:"Persona cannot be resolved to a type"

Solución: Elimina la declaración de un package y asegúrate de que ambas clases están en el mismo paquete.
Eso garantiza que las clases puedan reconocerse mutuamente.
